# 2 Tkinter frames and 1 not expanding on y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have an app with a gui written in Python 3 using Tkinter. I have 2 frames that contain buttons and I have setup the buttons and frames to expand with the window.

When I expand the window though, the top frame expands in all directions but the bottom frame only expands on the x axis.

**This is the code setting up the frames and main window:**

```
# Main Window
self.master = master
master.title('Calculator')
master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Top Frame
topfrm = tkinter.Frame(master, bg='#000000')
topfrm.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
for x in range(4):
    topfrm.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
for y in range(4):
    topfrm.rowconfigure(y, weight=1)

# Bottom Frame
btmfrm = tkinter.Frame(master, bg='#484848')
btmfrm.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
for x in range(4):
    btmfrm.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
for y in range(5):
    btmfrm.rowconfigure(y, weight=1)
```

**This is the code generating the buttons:**

```
r = 2
c = 0
for t in self.topfrmbtns:
    btn = tkinter.Button(topfrm, text=self.char(t), width=5, fg='#FFFFFF', bg='#000000', bd=0, command=lambda t=t: self.assmeth(t))
    btn.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='nsew')
    btn.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, e=btn: e.configure(bg="#A9A9A9"))
    btn.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, l=btn: l.configure(bg="#000000"))
    c += 1
    if c > 3:
        c = 0
        r += 1
for b in self.btmfrmbtns:
    btn = tkinter.Button(btmfrm, text=self.char(b), width=5, fg='#FFFFFF', bg='#808080', bd=0, command=lambda b=b: self.assmeth(b))
    btn.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='nsew')
    btn.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, e=btn: e.configure(bg="#A9A9A9"))
    btn.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, l=btn: l.configure(bg="#808080"))
    c += 1
    if c > 3:
        c = 0
        r += 1
```

Comment: You only row/column configure for the zero row/column on master.

Comment: @CurlyJoe I tried to configure row 1 but it just added a rectangle between the buttons in the top frame and the ones in the bottom frame

Comment: "I tried to configure row 1"--can't debug your code without code.  Works as expected on my machine.

Comment: @CurlyJoe Thank you for pointing me in the right direction with row configure. I was getting a rectangle between the buttons because I didn't reset the r and c variables to zero in the btm btn code. Top frame btns start on row 2 but the btm frame btns start on 0. No way to know that though without the rest of the code.